# android editText multiline return to line not working with swiftkey

Tags: android

I have the following edit text

```
    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                android:minHeight="90dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor" />
```

Every reference shows that the code is correct and in fact the text wraps to multiline. But the enter key doesn't go to the new line when i use swiftkey keyboard (Google keyboard works fine)
any idea of how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered switching to the default keyboard.  It might solve your issue.

See this answer [Set EditText to be Multiline(Enter is carrige return) and not display suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430328/set-edittext-to-be-multilineenter-is-carrige-return-and-not-display-suggestion) for more details.

Comment: Yes it did solve it. But I can't ask all the users who will install the app to switch to their default keyboard if using swiftkey. Whatsapp works with multiline on swiftkey so there should a solution.

Comment: have you found solution to this ?

Comment: @DanyY have you found the solution for this?

Comment: @DiaaSaada nope, left the project long ago :)